# In WordPress, one jQuery function works fine, but another doesn't. Both on same page. Tried on separate page. No love

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Here is the view source from the page now. See the `<p>` and `<br />` tags added? Would that break things?

```
        <p><script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</p>
<p>$j.(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.jw_window').each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 762; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 426;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $j(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $j(this).height();  // Current image height</p>
<p>        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if(width > maxWidth){
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $j(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $j(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }</p>
<p>        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if(height > maxHeight){
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $j(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $j(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }
</script><br />
<script type='text/javascript'>
$j(document).ready(function() {</p>
<p>$j('.panel_2').hide();</p>
<p>      $j('.work').click(function(){
            $j('.panel').fadeOut(function(){
            $j('.panel_2').fadeIn();
            });
      });
});
</script></p>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAL4J/)

Comment: Oh, it works just fine in an HTML doc, but won't in WP. Yet, the first code works (mostly) fine in WP. I should add that I'm using the CodeLibs plugin and have the code added to functions.php utilizing the latest jQuery library.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that jquery starting line. I use `$(function() {`  Not saying it's wrong, but looks strange to me

Comment: I've also used - $(document).ready(function() { - to no avail. Yet, even with what exists, the dynamic sizing function still works.

Comment: @Rodolfo: `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` is the standard way to call jQuery in [`noConflict` mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which is the common way to load jQuery in the WordPress environment.

Comment: I would definetly try to change all the `$` into `jQuery` - wordpress can sometimes cause those small syntax problems . It can not hurt to try. and by the way , using js console will tell you exactly what the problem is .

Answer (score 1):

When working in WordPress or any other framework that may already be using jQuery or have a plugin that is using jQuery, it is important to use a `noConflict()` statement.

You only need to use it once, but as stack order is important in jQuery, it needs to be the first line of jQuery you are implementing whether in external .js files or inline scripts.

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j.(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.jw_window').each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 762; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 426;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $j(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $j(this).height();  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if(width > maxWidth){
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $j(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $j(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if(height > maxHeight){
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $j(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $j(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }
</script>
```

Now you need to keep in mind that you need to continue using `$j` in your next scripts. So your next script goes as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$j(document).ready(function() {

$j('.panel_2').hide();

      $j('.work').click(function(){
            $j('.panel').fadeOut(function(){
            $j('.panel_2').fadeIn();
            });
      });
});
</script>
```

Also, you don't need to pass the `$` as a parameter in your document ready statement, so I removed that for you.

Comment: Still no love. Checking the source, however, I found that WP is adding a <p> tag to the code. Could that be the problem? If so, I guess I'll have to call it remotely. If so, I'll need to know how to do that. I haven't used jQuery with WP before.

Comment: Why are you adding this to the wysiwyg, code belongs in the actual file.

Comment: I guess I just don't know how, yet.